# JSF: ContextAwarePropertyNotFoundException/javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2, propertynotfoundexception

I have a JSF page **home.xhtml** with some JSF components / view and let's say it is currently loaded in a (Firefox) browser popup window named `test-popoup-win`. Now I try to access the same page/url, **home.xhtml?query=JSF**, with additional url parameters, from another (Firefox) browser window, which is supposed to load different/new set of components, based on new search context (?query=JSF). And this loads home.xhtml in the same browser popup window, named `test-popup-win`, overriding the previous JSF components / view. In the backend servlet code, I am actually **redirecting** to the same page, home.xhtml?query=JSF.

But instead of showing the new view, it throws the following error. The log shows that a property was not found. I can confirm that the property not found, belongs to the old view / bean. But if I click continue on my custom error page, I get the new view without any issue.

Please help/advice, by suggesting a way which could clear previous view cleanly and load the new view or any other way for issue fix. Let me know if I am missing any inputs. Thank you very much.

**Is there any good way to debug this kind of JSF issue ?**

**Update:** One may-not-be-good temporary workaround (I dont even call it solution) could be to ignore the exception in **FacesErrorHandlingServlet** class. ***I am still trying/looking for a good solution, please share if you have one***

```
*15:58:55,495 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10) **javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.test.ContainerBean' does not have the property 'testJsonData'.**
15:58:55,496 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
15:58:55,496 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:112)
15:58:55,497 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at **com.test.FacesErrorHandlingServlet**.service(FacesErrorHandlingServlet.java:44)
15:58:55,497 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor293.invoke(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
15:58:55,536 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10) **Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.test.ContainerBean' does not have the property 'testJsonData'.**
15:58:55,537 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:661)
15:58:55,537 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:290)
15:58:55,537 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
15:58:55,538 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
15:58:55,538 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:166)
15:58:55,539 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
15:58:55,539 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
15:58:55,540 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-10)     ... 82 more*
```

Comment: without reading the entire q', somewhere in your code you try to access `testJsonData` property inside `ContainerBean` , but it does not exists or no getter/setter... check it out

Comment: are you placing your bean as argument with `ui:param` ?

Comment: just make sure you don't invoke unexisting getter/setters on your beans, or make sure all beans share the same properties (inheritance) or wrap your components (that try to access your getters) with `rendered="#{myBean.typeOfBean eq 'theOneWithThatProperty'}"` or something like that

Comment: Please note that I have moved some of my comments into original post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't invoke unexisting getter/setters on your beans, or make sure all beans share the same basic properties (inheritance) or wrap your components (which try to access your getters) with `rendered="#{myBean.typeOfBean eq 'theOneWithThatProperty'}"` or something like that...

Comment: Pls advice if there is any generic solution for _Make sure you don't invoke unexisting getter/setters on your beans_ I am afraid the other two solutions may not suit my case, where I have many many beans. Thank you.

Comment: My answer holds the ideas that I can suggest you to use, maybe there are some other way of which I didn't think... If you post your code snippet me or other will be able to help you more